# Вёрстка IE Mozilla , не верно работает filter

Tags: css, firefox, internet-explorer

только один Google Chrome отображает верно ! Как именно нужно настроить кроссбраузерные стили что бы изображение стало чёрно белым ? Я делал так :

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
-ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
```

Вот сам пациент : [Пример вёрстки на хостинге](http://myatlanta.pe.hu/templates1/)

В общем для тех кому это будет интересно - даже в сети примеры не работают , ни делают изображение backwhite и ни какие SVG фильтры тоже не работают , только подмена изображения спасает . Нету лучшего  ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фильтры давно устарели, хоть их поддержка и остались в некоторых браузерах.

Впервые этот атрибут появился в Internet Explorer 4(изначально с префиксом `-ms-`, а потом и без) для использования фильтров DirectX в веб. Начиная с 8-й версии, данный атрибут при валидации помечался как устаревший. В IE 10 разработчики удалили поддержку данного атрибута. А в Edge его не добавляли совсем.

Google Chrome пока сохранил префиксный вариант этого атрибута(`-webkit-filter`), хоть он и тоже помечен устаревающим.

Mozilla Firefox сохранил только его безпрефиксный вариант(`filter`). Вы вместо него используете уже удаленный `-moz-filter`, поэтому он у вас и не работает.

---

Продолжать использовать этот атрибут в настоящее нельзя, т.к. в ближайшее время его поддержка может быть удалена и из других браузеров, помимо IE.

В примечаниях к выпуску IE10, компания Microsoft настоятельно рекомендовала вместо этого фильтра использовать давно доступные возможности css3:

- вместо фильтра `Alpha` следует использовать свойство `opacity`
- вместо `AlphaImageLoader` использовать `background-image`
- вместо `Gradient` - `background-image: linear-gradient()`
- `DropShadow` - `text-shadow` либо `box-shadow`
- `Matrix` - `transform` и `transform-origin`
- вместо экзотических фильтров(в том числе и `Grayscale`) - SVG-фильтры, либо преобразования в `canvas`-е на JavaScript.

  Пример использования SVG-фильтра `saturate` для создания эффекта, аналогичного требуемому вам:

  ```html
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <filter id="grayscale">
            <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"/>
       </filter>
       <image filter="url(#grayscale)" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="http://myatlanta.pe.hu/templates1/img/blackwhite/pic1.jpg" />
  </svg>
  ```

Comment: понятно , но как же выполнить это в IE ? Для FF получилось

Comment: @LenovoID, через`filter`? Никак. Этого аттрибута там уже нет. В Google Chrome и Mozilla Firefox вероятно тоже удалят скоро. А так, в последнем предложении моего ответа написано же:
"используйте SVG-фильтры, либо преобразования в canvas-е на JavaScript".
Это - единственно правильное кросплатформенное решение на данный момент. А использование фильтров лучше немедленно удалить, в том числе и для Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: а как это использовать " svg фильтры " ?

Comment: я даже пример нашёл в сети http://labs.voronianski.com/css3-grayscale/ и тоже в ie не работает

Comment: @LenovoID, там не указанный в заголовке "css3" - там точно такое-же использование устаревшего до его появления атрибута *filter

Comment: вы так и не сказали как использовать и где брать этот фильтр

Comment: @LenovoID, добавил пример в ответ(используется вместо img)

Comment: а теперя получается что надо каждый img списывать через svg ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32895/discussion-between-lenovoid-and-sergey-rufanov).

Comment: А для размытия нужно `canvas` использовать?